# Micropython 1.9.3 - How to compile .py @micropython.native code into .mpy?

Tags: python, micropython

I'm on [Micropython 1.9.3](https://github.com/micropython/micropython). I know how to use `mpy-cross` to turn a `.py` into a compiled python `.mpy` that can be executed by the Micropython virtual machine.

The problem is that if I try to compile using `@micropython.native` i.e. compile the Python script to native code instead of bytecode, I get an error:

```
../../mpy-cross/mpy-cross -o build/frozen_mpy/./frozentest.mpy -s frozentest.py  frozentest.py
```

> ValueError: can only save bytecode

On the following `.py`

```
@micropython.native
def native_add(a,b):
    return (a+b)

c = native_add(2342,4542)
```

**QUESTION**

Is it not possible to embed native code in `.mpy` format? Did I miss some option in [`mpy-cross/mpconfigport.h`](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/mpy-cross/mpconfigport.h)?

Only thing I changed is:

`#define MICROPY_EMIT_THUMB          (0) // changed it to 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from someone on [micropython forum](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4014&p=22999#p22992):

> You cannot. It is an TODO item. If you want to put it into flash
>   memory, you can embed it as frozen source code in some ports. Just put
>   these files in a subdirectory called scripts, like esp8266/scripts or
>   stm32/scripts. But it will still be compiled at import time and
>   consume RAM. Typically, that should not hurt, when this variant of
>   coding is used only for small, time-critical sections of the code.